# Не сравниваются строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начну с кода.

**Получаю данные из БД**

```
self.clients = [row for row in self.connect.execute(self.select_allClient)]
```

**Далее использую**

```
s = self.w_phone.text()
s = str(s).replace('+7', '').replace(' ', '').replace('-', '').replace('(', '').replace(')','')
    for e in self.clients:
        if (str(e[3]) == str(s)):
            //---//
```

где:

s - номер, введенный в элементе управления

e[3] строка из self.clients, 3 иднекс содержит в себе номер.

переменные получаются полностью идентичны. Далее приложу скрин с дебаггером.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так ?

Comment: разве пробел в вашем массиве (`e[3]`) сам исчезает?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
if (str(e[3]) in str(s)):
```

Comment: Попробовал, ничего не изменилось. Я подозреваю, что тут играет роль то, что я беру это из бд. Хотя опять же, я даже из-за этого привел к строковой переменной одной и той же. Как-то непонятно.

Comment: @GermanGettsel, вам же Bookin в комментариях к вопросу уже ответил. Чем вас его ответ не устроил?

Comment: Переутомился видимо тогда, всем спасибо и извините ) Не знаю. стоит его оставлять или удалить вопрос ?